# pandas FutureWarning: Downcasting object dtype arrays on .fillna, .ffill, .bfill is deprecated and will change in a future version

Tags: python, pandas, downcast

In order to print dataframes nicely using [tabulate](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate), so that `NaN` and `NaT` are printed as empty cells, I've been using this successfully:

```py
print(tabulate(df.astype(object).fillna("")))
```

Now, this causes the following warning:

> FutureWarning: Downcasting object dtype arrays on .fillna, .ffill,
> .bfill is deprecated and will change in a future version. Call
> result.infer_objects(copy=False) instead.

I don't know what I should do instead now. I certainly don't see how `infer_objects(copy=False)` would help as the whole point here is indeed to *force* converting everything to a string representation and filling in missing values with empty strings.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] and your pandas version? I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: @mrgou, I am also having this issue with fillna. In my case, I am replacing Na with False, boolean. 
```
<ipython-input-50-aed301f4f635>:2: FutureWarning: Downcasting object dtype arrays on .fillna, .ffill, .bfill is deprecated and will change in a future version. Call result.infer_objects(copy=False) instead. To opt-in to the future behavior, set `pd.set_option('future.no_silent_downcasting', True)`
```
I also feel that suppressing the warning is not the correct approach.

Were you able to resolve the problem?
Is this an issue we need to raise with pandas developers?

Answer (score 3):

### Convert the `DataFrame`/`Series` type first

Example:

```
df.astype(float).fillna(value)
```

### Infer the objects' type with `infer_objects`

```
df.infer_objects(copy=False).fillna(value)
```

Where `value` is a compatible type of the inferred objects:

---

Setting `pandas.set_option("future.no_silent_downcasting", True)` seems to work to remove the warning too, but I don't know if this is the correct behavior (as also pointed out by @mrgou in the comments).

---

### Explanation

The arrays are of the type `object` and, when you call `fillna`, it tries to infer the objects' type which issues this warning.

Comment: How to use ffill bfill etc on this. It just throws the warnings. And what the warning says to do doesn't work either.

Comment: Converting a Series or DataFrame dtype from object to a specific type like float, for example, should work as the first example I gave. What is the dtype of the Series or DataFrame? What kind of data is contained in it?

Comment: As @mozway mentioned, which version of pandas issues the warning with `fillna`, and on what min reprex?  I get a similar warning using `replace`, as in the other answers, but I don't get any warning using `fillna` for any example I have tried.

Comment: Version 2.2.1. I think it has more to do with data conversion. The series was initially of int type, then replaced some values with NaNs, then used fillna causing the warning. The dtype was int, then object, then fillna complained about the implicit conversion. Hope you get to reproduce it with this info.

Comment: @MaiconMauricio, if you did that all in one cell, or in a script, it was probably the `replace` that issued the warning.

Comment: Neither of these solutions work for the following two examples: `pd.Series(["Zero", 5, 2.3]).replace("Zero", 0)` and `pd.Series([False, True, float("nan")]).fillna(False)`. The first solution fails with ValueError for the first example (when applying `astype(float)`), and gives the wrong result for the second example (when applying `astype(bool)`); The second solution `infer_objects(copy=False)` keeps the FutureWarning for both examples; The third solution (set option "future.no_silent_downcasting") returns objects instead of floats or bools.

Comment: Thank you, @kadee and joe. I'll be looking more in depth into the correctness of my answer as soon as I have time to.

Answer (score 3):

In case of following distinct examples:

```py
ser1 = pd.Series([False, True, float("nan")])
ser1 = ser1.fillna(False)
```

and

```py
ser2 = pd.Series(["Zero", 5, 2.3])
ser2 = ser2.replace("Zero", 0)
```

the use of an option context combined with `infer_objects` at the end seems to be the most generic solution to get rid of the FutureWarning:

```py
with pd.option_context("future.no_silent_downcasting", True):
    ser1 = ser1.fillna(False).infer_objects(copy=False)
```

and

```py
with pd.option_context("future.no_silent_downcasting", True):
    ser2 = ser2.replace("Zero", 0).infer_objects(copy=False)
```

Probably better is to be more specific and use `astype(bool)` and `astype(float)` instead of `infer_objects(copy=False)` in the above.

Remark that other proposed solutions don't work in this case:

1. The use of `infer_objects(copy=False)` before `fillna` or `replace`:

```py
ser1.infer_objects(copy=False).fillna(False)
ser2.infer_objects(copy=False).replace("Zero", 0)
```

doesn't get rid of the FutureWarning.

2. The use of `astype` before `fillna` or `replace` is even more dangerous as it returns the wrong result for the first example:

```py
ser1.astype(bool).fillna(False)
```

and raises a ValueError for the second example:

```py
ser2.astype(float).replace("Zero", 0)
```

3. I would not recommend setting `pandas.set_option("future.no_silent_downcasting", True)` as this may hide issues elsewhere.

Comment: This solved a similar problem I was having. However, the syntax in the context manager is `pd.option_context` instead of `pd.option.context`.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue today and I'm still looking for a fix myself. In your case, I must admit I don't know what calling `astype(object)` twice does. However, as the error message mentions, you can try avoiding this and cast your data to strings instead (if that's feasible for the data you're handling). Then, you can use [pd.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas.DataFrame.replace) like so:

```
df.astype(str).replace(to_replace=["nan", "None"], value=(""))
```

Of course, you probably want to adapt `to_replace` to include the NaN and NaT you're searching for. On my system, `astype(str)` converts `NaN` to `nan`, so it might be similar for you and `NaT`.

Comment: The duplicate `astype` was a typo. I fixed it. Eventually, I think the warning is a false alarm: I added `pd.set_option('future.no_silent_downcasting', True)` expecting that forcing the new behavior would cause an exception to be raised... But it didn't, and the warning was not shown again.

Answer (score 2):

I just was in a similar situation. This line of code has worked for years and I just now find out its being deprecated.

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel,dtype='str')
df.replace({r'\n': ' '}, regex=True)
```

I had to update it to this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel,dtype='str')
df.astype(str).replace(to_replace=['\n', ' '], value=(''))
```

As I had received this warning:

```
FutureWarning: Downcasting behavior in `replace` is deprecated and will be removed 
in a future version. To retain the old behavior, explicitly call 
`result.infer_objects(copy=False)`. To opt-in to the future behavior, set 
`pd.set_option('future.no_silent_downcasting', True)`
  df = df.replace({r'\n': ' '}, regex=True)
```